# How to use array operators for type bytea[]?

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to use [array operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html) on a type of `bytea[]`?

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    metadata bytea[]
);

SELECT * FROM test WHERE test.metadata && ANY($1);

// could not find array type for data type bytea[]
```

If it's not possible, is there an alternative approach without changing the type from bytea[]?

postgresql 12.x

Comment: the idea is to store and compare hashes. It's unusual, and we could change our data model, but I would still like to know why this doesn't work.

Comment: It's a sha512 of an identifier. Thanks for the suggestion, but I want to know why this doesn't work. I updated the question to be more precise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `ANY`, just compare the arrays directly using an array constructor and array functions

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    metadata bytea[]
);

INSERT INTO public.test (metadata) VALUES('{"x","y"}');

SELECT * FROM test t WHERE metadata && array[E'\x78'::bytea];
```

When using [ANY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html#id-1.5.8.28.16), the left-hand expression is evaluated and compared to each element of the right-hand array using the given operator, which must yield a Boolean result. So the original sql was trying to do something like `bytea[] && bytea`.

This applies not only for `bytea[]`, but any array type e.g `text[]` or `integer[]`.

Comment: Based on the doc, I don't think `test.metadata = ANY($1);` should work. i.e it's trying to compare an array to a single value multiple times.

Comment: Ah, right it's the other way round, sorry: `$1 = any(test.metadata)`